# Compare a string value to an array and if it matches get the index of the array item

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

I'm trying to code a notification system but I'm having issues with a problem so I have a function named `getAlerts` that return an array like this:

```
[{"id":3,"user_id":"1","asset":"xyz","price":600,"position":"above"},{"id":4,"user_id":"1","asset":"xyz","price":300,"position":"above"}]
```

Then I have a websocket with setInterval that keeps checking the value every 1 second how do I compare the price string from websocket to all the price key in the array with regard to their user_id key? let's say that the current price matches one of the price key in the array how do I get the index of the matched key? I've done lot of Googling but unfortunately those questions compared two arrays and still couldn't find anything on getting the index of the matched key.

NodeJS Code

```
const main = (ticker) => {
    let list = [];
    
  
        if (assetprice > list) {
             // get user_id of matched key
            // do something
        }
    
   
};
```

Comment: A simple filter such as: `alerts.filter(v => v.price == 41000)` gives you all matching alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to find the index of the first matching element using a predicate. Alternatively, use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to immediately get the result:

```js
const data = [ 'ABC123', 'DEF456', 'ABCDEF123456' ];

const index = data.findIndex(v => v.includes('DEF'));
console.log(index); // 1

const value = data.find(v => v.includes('DEF'));
console.log(value); // 'DEF456'
```

I'm simply using strings and `String.prototype.includes` as data/predicate, but this can also work with your list of objects where you check e.g. `v.user_id === user_id`.

Comment: The market price changes every milisecond `Array.prototype.find ` won't work that's why I wanna check if the price is greater or lesser than current market price

Comment: Why won't it work? If it's because `===` is too strict, the predicate can be whatever, it's just a function. You're free to use `.find(isMatch)` or `.find(v => v.field <= 123)` and such.